# 2014 Dodge RAM 1500 Hemi 5.7 Liter 4x4 - Loud Squeal

Tags: noise, troubleshooting, dodge, ram, hemi

Last night I was just out for a drive down the highway and I went to turn off that highway onto another and I decided I haven't done a burnout in a while so I gave it a shot and shortly after that when I got my truck up to speed at anywhere around 80km/h to 100km/h (highway speed) it started to make a high pitch squeal.

***It's loud enough that I can't tell if its coming from the front or rear end of the truck.***

The squeal goes away when I accelerate or decelerate. Its only there when I keep a steady speed. My truck has about 42,000 kms on it so it is not that old at all.

**Can anybody tell me what the source of the squeal might be?**

Comment: You may want to check your driveline, but a nondescript  squeal is hard to diagnose over the internet. If you have *any* other information, it would be of great assistance.

Comment: Also check to see if it does this while just Erving the motor in park or neutral.... Help to narrow down if motor or drive component

Comment: it doesn't do it in park or neutral when i rev it. but ill try driving down the highway and putting it in neutral and see if it does anything as soon as i can

Comment: Did you run your experiment.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad - OP said the noise went away so there's no way to continue diagnosing the problem.